# Sources of Free Stock Market (Nasdaq/NYSE) Data - Tick by Tick

Tags: online-data-source, historical-data, historical-analysis

I'm a developer and would like to create a stock market replay tool. i.e. I'd like to be able to replay a particular day (or subset of a day) tick by tick to test my trading hypotheses. Oddly, the coding is the simple part. Finding accurate tick by tick data for a specific day is more difficult. Can anyone provide suggestions for a source of free tick-by-tick data?
Thank you

Comment: does this help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api

Answer (score 3):

There are no free reliable tick by tick data providers. The best data you will have access to for free is maybe 1 minute intervals.

-I was a professional trader for a few years.